# Get element by ID within inflatered LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

How to get element by ID within inflatered LinearLayout?

Here is my code which works fine and I see the created child LinearLayouts.

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutContainer);
LayoutInflater inflater;
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

final int size = grandTotalStatsRespond.getStatZoneItems().size();
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
    StatZoneItem statZoneItem = grandTotalStatsRespond.getStatZoneItems().get(j);
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.loader_total_stat_item, null);

    // Here I need to find TableRow and TextView within LinearLayout  by its ID
    // and set values of statZoneItem object.                   

    root.addView(l);
}
```

Comment: this might *freeze your UI* in case of large lists !!

Comment: @SantanuSur Thanks for the comment! I plan to use about 10-20 items only. Is it too much?

Comment: i think *just* textviews wont cause much harm, but its better to replace it with recyclerView !

Comment: @SantanuSur Cool! Thanx, bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
    StatZoneItem statZoneItem = grandTotalStatsRespond.getStatZoneItems().get(j);
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.loader_total_stat_item, null);

    // Here I need to find TableRow and TextView with LinearLayout  by its ID

      TableRow  tableRow = l.findViewById(R.id.tableRowID);
      TextView  textView = l.findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
      textView.setText("NILESH");
    // and set values from  statZoneItem object.                   

    root.addView(l);
}
```